# JSON debugging: JSON to CSV parsing

Tags: python, json, mongodb, csv

We have a syslog-ng server that get Mongodb logs that contain JSON in the log, The sample log is below:

```
2016-10-17 19:54:12 f:local1.p:info h:10.133.126.79 prog:sharmongo-log m:sharmongo-log 2016-10-17T19:54:04.943+0330 I COMMAND  [conn5573] command CLM.BillingAccount command: count { count: "BillingAccount", query: { $or: [ { billingAccount.customerCode: "C8088810719" } ] } } planSummary: COUNT_SCAN { billingAccount.customerCode: 1.0 } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:122 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 2 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } } } protocol:op_query 216ms
```

We need to insert the incomming logs to the database, first of all I need to parse the log to CSV, I want to write a python script to change the incomming logs to CSV. as you can see a part of the log is JSON (as described in [MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/audit-message/) documentation ant this [girthub](https://github.com/rueckstiess/mongodb-log-spec) link it is in JSON format). the JSON portion of logs are like this:

```
command: count {
    count: "BillingAccount",
    query: {
        $or: [{
            billingAccount.customerCode: "C8088810719"
        }]
    }
}
planSummary: COUNT_SCAN {
    billingAccount.customerCode: 1.0
}
keyUpdates: 0 writeConflicts: 0 numYields: 0 reslen: 122 locks: {
    Global: {
        acquireCount: {
            r: 2
        }
    },
    Database: {
        acquireCount: {
            r: 1
        }
    },
    Collection: {
        acquireCount: {
            r: 1
        }
    }
}
protocol: op_query 216 ms
```

but I see a lot of errors in it that when I want to parse it with a python `json` library I get an error. I need to change it to a form that I doesn't give me an error anymore, first I quoted every key as they were not. but again I got the following errors:

[image]
[image]

besides these errors' one major problem is that I got more than one JSON in log that it caused me more errors , I need to know If there is a python library to help me to parse this JSON. What do you suggest to solve this problem?

Comment: You need to wrap everything in `{` `}` so that it becomes a json object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"command": "count" {
```

Is not JSON and that could probably be the reason.

```
"command": "count",
           { ......
```

This might make sense in terms of JSON.